# How to access 'this' inside a callback function in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, braintree

I am trying to set a variable declared at the beginning of the class (a boolean) to true once a callback is called, but I keep getting a TypeScript erorr.

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'nonReceived' of undefined
```

Here is my code:

```
  finalizeToken(){
  braintree.setup(JSON.parse(this.finalToken), 'dropin', {
     container: 'dropin-container',
     defaultFirst: true,
      form: 'checkout-form',
      onPaymentMethodReceived: function (obj) {
        this.nonReceived = true;
      localStorage.setItem('nonce', obj.nonce);
    }
  });  
}
```

The brintree-setup connect to Braintree Payments, and awaits user payment info. Once they submit the form, I need the variable "this.nonReceived" to be set to true.

Comment: Bind `this` or use arrow functions

Comment: How do I bind this?

Comment: See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: What would that look like in my example? Where would the bind function go?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you use ES5 syntax you could use `function(){}.bind(this)` to bind the callback with the context but with Typescript you can use ES6 syntax and use arrow function `(parameters) => {function_body}` which bind current context implicitly.

Comment: Would the binding go onto where the function was called, or the function definition?

Comment: It helped , Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks. ES5 syntax worked for me inside ondrop for files drag and drop on a div.

Comment: This code may help someone:
   this.dndContainer.ondrop = function (e: any) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation()
      this.className = "";
      var droppedFiles = e.dataTransfer.files;
     
      this.fileStore.push.apply(this.fileStore, droppedFiles);
      if (this.fileStore.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("divDroppedFiles").style.display = "block";
      }

      return false;
    }.bind(this);